# Confusing 406 errors

Tags: caching, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-406

I have a page in a Sitefinity website (http://www.pcma.org/attend-learn/topics) that is sending back 406 Not Acceptable errors for a few static javascript and css files. The strange thing is, it's only happening on www.pcma.org, not pcma.org (without 'www').

It doesn't happen on all files either, so I'm stumped. Has anyone run across something similar? We're on IIS 7 and Sitefinity 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a caching issue. We had inadvertently set the cache's max age to be 31 days in our web.config:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="31.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

A user or a bot then must have come along and tried to request the problem files, and our [ATS proxy](http://trafficserver.apache.org) cached the 406 response and happily continued to serve the error page even after the problems with the files were resolved.

Clearing the proxy cache and changing the `cacheControlMaxAge` attribute to 1 hour resolved the issue.